# moveWordForward: on ⌥-f in El Capitan doesn't repeat

Tags: macos, keyboard, emacs, cocoa

I've used [Jacob Rus' cocoa text system bindings](https://github.com/jrus/cocoa-text-system) for many years to give me more emacs like bindings in cocoa text fields (apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html). Since El Capitan I find that option-f which does moveWordForward: only works once and doesn't repeat if I hold down the keys. option-b (moveWordBackward:) does repeat as it always has and so does option-rightarrow (which I assume also does moveWordForward:).

I played with KeyBindingsEditor and found that option-control-f is bound to moveWordForward: in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict and it repeats (also that option-right is bound to moveWordRight:). It also confirmed that option-f is bound to moveWordForward: in the Standard and my user KeyBinding.dict.

I've checked for other bindings on option-f in System Preferences and haven't found any. Anyone know what might be wrong or how I can debug this further?

OS X 10.11.1, 3.4 GHz i7 iMac, 24GB RAM, 1TB Fusion, Apple Wired Keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Turns out a new keyboard fixed it.