# Why does moveWordBackward: auto-repeat, but moveWordForward: does not?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I have the following in my `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file (among other key bindings):

```
  "~b"    = (moveWordBackward:);
  "~f"    = (moveWordForward:);
```

Pressing and holding <kbd>⌥b</kbd> starts auto-repeating after a brief pause, as expected. However, pressing and holding <kbd>⌥f</kbd> does **not**. It has been this way for multiple macOS versions. I recently upgraded to Ventura by doing a clean installation and adding my custom `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file. I thought this would fix whatever the problem was, but no: it still doesn't auto-repeat.

Essentially the same question was asked by someone [in 2015](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213193/movewordforward-on-f-in-el-capitan-doesnt-repeat) but they reported that the problem was their keyboard. In my case, it happens with every external or internal keyboard I've tried (including a brand new keyboard I'm typing this on).

**Why does <kbd>⌥f</kbd> for `moveWordForward:` fail to auto-repeat**?

In case it's relevant, [here is my complete `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file](https://gist.github.com/mhucka/5468f89c1d6b1de2021369b445000a8d).

Comment: No clue why, but to test - try removing the bindings then see if opt/b produces a line of  ∫∫∫∫ & opt/f gives ƒƒƒƒ then check if the default opt/left right arrow *does* jump repeatedly by word.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the idea. I tested it. Using the built-in laptop keyboard and no bindings for those keys, option-f does _not_ auto-repeat the ƒ character (but opt-b auto-repeats ∫). Are you saying that option-f _does_ auto-repeat for you?

Comment: Yes, both do. I've never found one that doesn't; though it's not a feature I use often, I do have it intentionally set to repeat rather than pop up that awful 'letter chooser'

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your super-fast reply! OK, then that must mean something is interfering with auto-repeat in my configuration and it is probably not related to key bindings. Sigh.

Comment: Yeah, it's a puzzler - but at least that simple test removed one thing from the equation… even if it didn't really point to what **is** responsible.